# Does Tor send the website domain name or IP to the relays?

Tags: dns, browser, privacy, tor

When a Tor client wants to connect to a website, say: google.com, does it resolve its IP first, then send the IP over the relays? or does it pass the domain name which gets resolved by the last exit node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the client. Tor *has* the ability to remotely resolve names and your local Tor node will always use Tor-based resolution if asked to connect to a domain name, but it all depends on the client apps actually *providing* the name and not doing their own name resolution locally.

For example, Firefox (a SOCKS client) has an option named "Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5" – this enables remote (Tor-based) name resolution as long as SOCKS version 5 is selected.

Meanwhile the older SOCKS v4 protocol does not have this capability at all; it only supports sending the IP address. (This is however added by version 4a. If you see programs specifically offering SOCKS v4a, that generally means they send the hostname.)

As another example, `curl` has a selection between "socks4" (sends IP address), "socks4a" (sends hostname), "socks5" (sends IP address), and "socks5h" (sends hostname) proxy types.

When the HTTP proxy mode is used, *usually* the full hostname is sent. If you're using a HTTP-to-SOCKS translator such as Polipo or Privoxy (which I remember having been used with Tor sometime in the last century), it depends on the translator's abilities in addition to the client's.